# Prolog, работа со списками

Tags: prolog

Вывести на экран список тех студентов, чьи увлечения полностью или частично удовлетворяют определенному списку.

```
domains
    sym_list=symbol*.
predicates
    student(real, symbol, integer, symbol, sym_list).
clauses
    student(101, alekseev, 1996, "I12", [football, tennis]).
    student(102, ivanov,   1996, "I12", [games, computer]).
    student(103, petrov,   1996, "I12", [football, tv]).
    student(104, orlov,    1996, "I12", [games, tennis]).
    student(201, sidorov,  1997, "I13", [games, web]).
    student(202, kruglov,  1997, "I13", []).
    student(203, vorobyev, 1997, "I13", [football, web]).
    student(204, lomov,    1997, "I13", [tv, web]).
```

---

У меня следующее решение:

```
domains
    sym_list=symbol*.
predicates
    student(real, symbol, integer, symbol, sym_list).
    intersect (sym_list, sym_list, sym_list).
    memb(symbol,sym_list).
    delete_all(symbol, sym_list, sym_list).
    list_set(sym_list,sym_list).
    find_student(sym_list, symbol).
clauses
    student(101, alekseev, 1996, "I12", [football, tennis]).
    student(102, ivanov,   1996, "I12", [games, computer]).
    student(103, petrov,   1996, "I12", [football, tv]).
    student(104, orlov,    1996, "I12", [games, tennis]).
    student(201, sidorov,  1997, "I13", [games, web]).
    student(202, kruglov,  1997, "I13", []).
    student(203, vorobyev, 1997, "I13", [football, web]).
    student(204, lomov,    1997, "I13", [tv, web]).

    %функция удаления повторяющихся элементов
    delete_all(_,[],[]).
    delete_all(X,[X|L], L1):- delete_all(X,L,L1).
    delete_all(X,[Y|L], [Y|L1]):-X<>Y, delete_all(X,L,L1).
    list_set([],[]).
    list_set([H|T],[H|T1]):-delete_all(H,T,T2), list_set(T2,T1).

    %поиск пересечения

    memb(_,[]) :- fail.
    memb(X,[X|_]) :- !.
    memb(X,[_|T]) :- memb(X,T).
    intersect([],_,[]).
    intersect([H|T],Y,[H|R]) :- memb(H,Y),intersect(T,Y,R), !.
    intersect([_|T],Y,R1) :- intersect(T,Y,R), list_set(R,R1), !.

    find_student(R1,Name):-I=R1, student(_,Name,_,_,R1), intersect(R1,I,Res), I=R1.
```

Не понимаю как связать эти функции с find_student, чтобы выводилось то, что требуется в задаче.

Answer (score 1):

А зачем делать отдельную функцию?
задаешь какое увлечение хочешь искать строкой, а после значение подставляешь в предикат

```
student(X,Y,1996,"I12",[football|Tail])
```

Хотя бы так.